# representing graph in c++ using vector<vector>

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to represent an undirected graph in c++ and then printing the vertices with their neigbours. But when i'm unable to understand the output here-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

 int reach(vector<vector<int> > &adj) {
  vector<vector<int> >::iterator it;
  vector<int>::iterator i;
  for (it = adj.begin(); it != adj.end(); ++it)
  {
     cout << (*(*it).begin()) << "outside"<< endl;

        for (i = (*it).begin(); i != (*it).end(); ++i)
        {
            cout << (*i) << "inside" << endl;

        }
   }
  return 0;
   }




int main() {
  size_t n, m;
  cin >> n >> m;
  vector<vector<int> > adj(n, vector<int>());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    adj[x - 1].push_back(y - 1);
    adj[y - 1].push_back(x - 1);
  }
  cout << reach(adj);
}
```

outside means it's the vertex and inside are its neigbours.

```
for the input 3 2 1 2 2 3 output is-

1outside
1inside
0outside
0inside
2inside
1outside
1inside
```

why is 1outside there 2 times ?  And shouldn't the output be

```
0outside
1inside
1outside
0inside
2inside
2outside
1inside
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You are never printing indices.

Comment: I think the main source of your confusion is that `*(*it).begin()` in the outer loop is the same thing as `*i`on the first iteration of the inner loop (that is, it's the first element of `*it`).

Comment: okay,i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your intent is for the first dimension of your two-dimensional vector to be the identity of the first point, with all second points, that the first point leads to, stored in the second dimension.

```
cout << (*(*it).begin()) << "outside"<< endl;
```

This does not print the value of the first dimension being iterated over. This prints the first value of the second dimension. Which is why you get duplicate output.

`it` is a random access iterator of the vector comprising the identity of the first point. If so,

```
 cout << (it-adj.begin()) << "outside"<< endl;
```

will reverse-engineer its index. But that's going to be too confusing.

It's more straightforward to rewrite the whole thing using index iteration on the outside, and range iteration on the inside:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<adj.size(); ++i)
{
     cout << i << "outside"<< endl;

     for (auto j: adj[i])
        cout << j << "inside" << endl;
}
```